# What Rails OAuth 2 server solution allows using same controllers with OAuth and form based auth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, authentication

I want to use the same controller for browser users (form-based auth) and OAuth API users. Seems like gems like [doorkeeper](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper) make controllers accept only OAuth 2.

Should I make a basic no-auth controller and two subclasses (one for OAuth, another for form-based)? Or is there a solution that allows it on one controller class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [oauth-plugin](https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin) allows this.  You can specify:

```
oauthenticate, :interactive => true
```

This will allow both logged in users, and OAuth users to access the same controller actions.

I wrote a blog post on [setting up an OAuth2 provider](http://blog.gazler.com/blog/2012/01/08/oauth2-provider-with-rails/) with oauth-plugin.  You can follow it for the most part, however you probably don't want to have an API base class, and you want to replace:

```
oauthenticate, :interactive => false
```

With:

```
oauthenticate, :interactive => true
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with doorkeeper, as you can pass in your own options to the filter:

```
doorkeeper_for :all, {:if => lambda{|c| !current_user}}
```

This will only have doorkeeper kick in if the user it not in logged (e.g. no current_user).